Steepest descent via pull-back metric
Many optimization/parameter estimation problem (curve fitting, training neuron network, etc.) can be formulated as follows: Let $\Omega$ be the parameter space and $M$ be the space of observed quantities, they are both Riemannian manifolds. And there is a map $f:\Omega\rightarrow M$ and a specified point $p_{obs}$, we need to minimize the geodesic distance $d_M(p_{obs},f(\omega))$ over $\omega\in \Omega$.
As an example, one can consider a linear regression on $(x_1,y_1)\,,\dots,(x_n,y_n)$, with $y=ax+b$, $a,b$ are parameters, we are minimizing $\sum_i(y_i-(ax_i+b))^2$. In our formulation $\Omega=\mathbb{R}^2$ and $M=\mathbb{R}^n$, both with Euclidean metric. The map $f$ is given by $(a,b)\mapsto (ax_1+b,\dots,ax_n+b)$ and the $p_{obs}$ is $(y_1,\dots,y_n)$.
So by steepest descent, the flow is given by gradient of pull-back contracting with inverse of Riemann metric tensor on $\Omega$. But there is another choice, one can use pull-back of metric on $M$. For which the metric on $\Omega$ is no longer necessary. There are obvious benefits: the metric on $\Omega$ are in general not canonical, say we can introduce another parameterization $a^{\prime}=10a$ and induced flow has 100-fold difference.
My question is:

Has this approach been studied? I guess it must be because it's a rather simple modification.
If yes, why it is not widely used?


Why is $\Omega$ simply connected?  In other words, why can't two points in $\Omega$ have more than one metric separation (be connected by two geodesics that are not homotopic to each other) under the pullback you want?  Even if we lift to universal covers for $M$ and $\Omega$, it's not clear that multi-valuedness for the pullback of the metric is avoided...

@EricTowers Yes we need more assumption to make (this formulation of) gradient descent work, but here we introduce the notion of Riemannian manifold as a tool to  look at local properties. For simplicity it does not harm to assume $M$ and $\Omega$ are convex open subset of Euclidean space, but the $f$ is non-linear so it's possible to have non-Euclidean metric.
